# Cakephp 1.3 Edit Acton Not Populating Field

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having a problem with my edit action and Im not sure what my problem is but my fields are not populating. In my model I have a function that retrieves 3 records based on an id, and I call that function in my controller, which in turn should populate data in the view. I have tried to debug but have had no luck. I have tried to use die(debug($this->data)); but I when I run the script the next page loads instead of displaying what is in $this->data, which is strange to me! With that said, here is what I've got. Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Model

```
public function declinationsForPolicyId($id = null) {
    if ($id) {
        $items = $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Declination.policy_id' => $id
            ),
            'limit' => 3,
            'contain' => array()
        ));
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $ret= $item['Declination'];
        }
        $ret = array('Declination' => $ret);

    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Controller

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        die(debug($this->data));
        $this->Declination->create();
            $this->data = $this->Declination->declinationsForPolicyId($id);
        if ($this->Declination->saveAll($this->data['Declination'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations saved.', true));
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'policies',
                'action' => 'view',
                $id
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations failed to save.', true));
        }
    } 

    $reasons = $this->Declination->Reason->find('list');
    $contactTypes = $this->Declination->ContactType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('id', 'reasons', 'contactTypes'));
}
```

View

```
 <div class="content" id="container">

    <?php echo $this->UiForm->create('Declination', array(
        'url' => array(
            'controller' => 'declinations',
            'action' => 'add',
            $id
        )
    )); ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
    <section  class="panel">


        <h4>Declination <?php echo ($i + 1); ?></h4>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.policy_id", array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'value' => $id
        )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.id", array(
            'type' => 'hidden'
        )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.first_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.last_name"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.company"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.contact_type_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.phone_number"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.reason_id"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.other", array(
            'label' => 'If other, please supply a reason'
        )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->UiForm->input("Declination.{$i}.dated", array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'readonly' => 'readonly',
            'data-datepicker' => ''
        )); ?>
    </section>
    <?php endfor; ?>

    <?php echo $this->UiForm->end(array('label'=>'Continue', 'class'=>'btn success large fr')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. There were a few changes I made throughout my application. I started by passing in the policy id in via the edit html link. After that my function seemed to work, as the id was set as the policy id. Also I made a slight change to my edit function. You can see the changes below.

Controller

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Declination->declinationsForPolicyId($id);
    } else {
        // some code

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Declinations failed to save.', true));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the info when the data is not empty, but when is empty (at first load of the page), you are just filling `id, reasons, contactType`.

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
       //everything you posted
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Declination->declinationsForPolicyId($id);
    }
} 

$reasons = $this->Declination->Reason->find('list');
$contactTypes = $this->Declination->ContactType->find('list');
$this->set(compact('id', 'reasons', 'contactTypes'));
```

}